# RStudio Viewer does not refresh automatically plotly plots

Tags: plotly, rstudio, refresh, viewer

I have two computers, each with Windows 10, R 4.2.2 and the last RStudio version.

On my home computer, the Viewer pane automatically refreshes when I adjust its size. This is the normal/expected behavior.

On my professional laptop, the Viewer does not refresh. This is annoying because I am using Plotly to show graphs in the Viewer pane, and the graph parameters (width of the bars, placement of the legend...) should be responsive to the pane's size.

To reproduce my bug, one needs to load `plotly` and run `plot_ly(x = c(1), y = "Test", type = 'bar')`. Then, change the Viewer width or height, and observe that the plot does not change. Clicking on the "Refresh viewer" icon on the top-right of the pane correctly adjusts the plot, but it should be done automatically when adjusting the pane, not manually.

I am not sure how to exactly reproduce the bug though, since I have it only in one computer and both seem to have the same configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Something happened to me before. If the packages is updated for your type of computer, try these two options:

1. Delete the package and re-install it! You can do it with `remove.packages("package_name")` function. And then install it again. (Check if are other related packages to the main one, and do the same with them). It just takes a few seconds to do the whole process.
2. If that does not work, uninstall R-Studio/Posit and install it again to clean the package relationships.